# Regular Expression for recognizing the string that contains only specific words

Tags: regex

I am very much new to regular expressions. What i am trying to do is, trying to check whether the input sentence is formed with **only certain words**.

For example, for a number in text format:

- `Seven Six Two`  is correct
- `I have Seven Six Two balloons` is invalid (other word than `seven`, `six` or `two` in this case).

For this, I have written a reg expression like `(Seven|Six|Two|One|Three)(\s*)`
But my regular expression is recognizing both the input as correct.

Can you please suggest me how to correct the regular expression to match the whole and only word with the specific list of words.

Comment: Why not search the following pattern `/Seven\sSix\sTwo/ims`

Comment: It is better to add some info like in which language/tools you want your expression (a unix grep/sed/perl/awk, windows vba/C/... to take common use) act differently with extended/limited regex features

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^(?!\s*$)(?:Seven|Six|Two|One|Three| )+$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tJ2mW5/6